# Creating an array that is split into two parts from results of a mysqli query

Tags: php

I'm not sure of the correct terminology (multidimensional?)for what I want to achieve, so I'll show you my code, and try to explain.
I am working in zen cart, which is why the database query uses $db->execute.

The following is inside a function to build my array

```
   $oID = (int)$oID;
   $combined =  $db->execute("SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_model,
                    op.products_name, op.products_quantity,
                    o.customers_name
                    FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " op
                    LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o
                    ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
                    WHERE op.orders_id = $oID" . $this->product_filter);

    while (!$combined->EOF) {
        $order_id = $combined->fields['orders_id'];
        $customers_name = $combined->fields['customers_name'];
        $products_name = $combined->fields['products_name'];
        $products_model = $combined->fields['products_model'];
        $products_quantity = $combined->fields['products_quantity'];

        $this_order_data = array(
                               'order' => $order_id,
                               'customer' => $customers_name,
                               'name' => $products_name,
                               'model' => $products_model,
                               'quantity' => $products_quantity
                              );
    echo'<pre>';print_r($this_order_data);echo'</pre>';
    $combined->MoveNext();
    }
```

This gives me results like

```
Array
(
[order] => 1913
[customer] => Customer A
[name] => Product 1
[model] => P1
[quantity] => 15
)
Array
(
[order] => 1913
[customer] => Customer A
[name] => Product 2
[model] => P2
[quantity] => 15
)
Array
(
[order] => 1912
[customer] => Customer B
[name] => Product 3
[model] => P3
[quantity] => 5
)
Array
(
[order] => 1911
[customer] => Customer C
[name] => Product 2
[model] => P2
[quantity] => 75
)
Array
(
[order] => 1911
[customer] => Customer C
[name] => Product 4
[model] => P4
[quantity] => 30
)
Array
(
[order] => 1910
[customer] => Customer D
[name] => Product 5
[model] => P5
[quantity] => 31
)
```

What I really want is to have it more like this

```
Array
(
[order] => 1911
[customer] => Customer C
) 
    Array
    (
    [name] => Product 2
    [model] => P2
    [quantity] => 75
    )
    Array
    (
    [name] => Product 4
    [model] => P4
    [quantity] => 30
    )
Array
(
[order] => 1910
[customer] => Customer D
)
    Array
    (
    [name] => Product 5
    [model] => P5
    [quantity] => 31
    )
```

So essentially, part of my sql results (order and customer) form one array, and then name, model and quantity are repeated for every line item under that order. Then it moves on to the next order.

How can I split my sql results to form two arrays, where one is inside the other?

Edit: The end goal is to be able to echo a report that shows an order id and customer name, followed by a list of the products that order contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If orders_id is a primary key for `TABLE_ORDERS` you can modify your code like this:

```
 $result = []; //somewhere early, before while, initialize empty array
```

and later:

```
 //replace from $this_order_data = array( ...
 $this_order_data = array(
                           'name' => $products_name,
                           'model' => $products_model,
                           'quantity' => $products_quantity
                         );
if (isset($result[$order_id])) {
  $result[$order_id]['products'][] = $this_order_data;
} else {
  $result[$order_id]['order_id'] = $order_id;
  $result[$order_id]['customer_name'] = $customer_name; //here we need the primary key
                                                    //exactly one customer per order
  $result[$order_id]['products'][] = $this_order_data;
}
$combined->MoveNext();
} //end while

var_dump(array_values($result)); //you can remove array_values, 
      //if you don't mind that the order ids are array keys.
```